# Validation in Web Forms for Marketers in Sitecore

Tags: validation, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I have few queries.

1. How can I apply MaxLength validation on Email and Telephone just like Single-Line Text field?

[image]

I tried to add MaxLength parameter in particular field of form. It is working but I do not want to display error message I want to stop user when user exceed.

2. I also want to apply only alpha validation on Single-Line Text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no out of the box control to limit the field length in the way you want, you would either have to create a custom form field or the easier option would be to use some Javascript and CSS to achieve something similar.

Using a similar method to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591630/is-accessing-droplist-value-of-sitecore-wffm-control-in-javascript-possible/32596823#32596823) I provided recently, create a CSS class called "limited-length" then add the following JS:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".limited-length").attr("maxlength", "150");
    });
})($scw);
```

To restrict the single-line text field to alpha only you can use the "Letter Only" validation option.

[image]

If you want to stop the user typing non-alpha characters into the box then you will need to bind a javascript/jquery function, using a similar method as above and [restrict the input to alpha keypress only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13237018/661447).

Comment: Kam's answer is the best answer to your questions. You can go down the route of creating a Custom Field Type based on the SingleLineText which will allow you to set the max limit per but Textbox but is more complex. If you need a slightly different RegEx to Sitecore's Letters Only, select Custom in the drop down list and enter your own there.